# How to remove UIColor that fills image in the red color in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

dear developers. I am reskinning an existing objective-c code (Xcode 8 project) and I run into an issue that all png images are automatically painted with red color, so I can't see any real look of the images when running an app in Simulator and on the real device.

I tried to use UIColor clearColor instead of UIColor redColor, but image just disappears.

How can I just show images "as is" with no color overlay at all?

Thank you very much for your help!

```
UIButton *temp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        temp.tag = 0;
        [self collectionClose:temp];

        CGFloat width, height;
        CGFloat centerX = _canvas.frame .size.height/2.0, centerY = _canvas.frame.size.width/2.0;
        UIImage *image = [self imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pack%ld%@_%zd.png", (long)packID, currentCollection, indexPath.row+1]
                              withColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I seen your code and there you have clearly written that button color red. The method which you have written is wrong. [UIButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]].

This will show image in button.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *temp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
temp.tag = 0;
[self collectionClose:temp];

CGFloat width, height;
CGFloat centerX = _canvas.frame .size.height/2.0, centerY = _canvas.frame.size.width/2.0;

NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pack%ld%@_%zd.png", (long)packID, currentCollection, indexPath.row+1];
[temp setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```